# Switch 302 redirect to 301 with Apache 2 ProxyPass in front of Tomcat 6

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, tomcat6, proxypass

I'm trying to optimise my site for SEO and it seems as though their is a 302 direct in action for the http requests.

I'm hosting my app on a Tomcat 6 server which lies behind an Apache 2 server. I use the ProxyPass method (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html) to forward all requests to port 8080 (the port my app is hosted on). I've seen a lot of advice on how to set the redirect type when using the VirtualHost method but none to do with ProxyPass.

The app is a Struts app that forwards users on to index.jsp when they hit the base url. Could this also be the issue?

I'm grateful for any help on this one! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this on struts, but you could do this on apache side.

In your configuration file, near ProxyPass directive add following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.jsp [R=301,L]
```